# `highline` gem is already installed, but `commander` refuses to install

Tags: ruby, rubygems, highline

When I type `gem install commander`, I get:

```
Error installing commander:
commander requires highline (~> 1.6.11)
```

I even did `gem install highline` ("Successfully installed highline-1.6.11") and I get the same error. What could be the cause of this error?

Comment: are you using `bundle` and/or `rvm`? maybe you have the correct `highline` version installed but other version in being loaded.

Comment: @fguillen: You are a genius. I was inside a `bundle exec bash` session. Exiting made it work.

Comment: no really but I'm happy you solve your problem :)

Comment: @fguillen, do you want to write an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you're in the appropiate `bundle` and/or `rvm` session context.

Maybe you have the correct `highline` version installed in one context but the gem is been loaded from another context.